# What is the distribution of a stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space
- $E$ be a Polish space and $\mathcal{E}$ be the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
- $X_t$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ with values in $(E,\mathcal{E})$

Then, $X:=(X_t,t\in I)$ is called a **stochastic process**. I've seen that people talk about the *distribution* $\mathcal{L}[X]$ of a stochastic process $X$, but how is $\mathcal{L}[X]$ defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E^I$ denote the set of all functions from $I$ to $E$.

Note that $X$ can be viewed as a mapping from $\Omega$ into $E^I$, with $[X(\omega)](t) = X_t(\omega)$.

Also, $X$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $E^I$ which is generated by all of the projections $\pi_t: E^I\to E$, given by $\pi_t(f) = f(t)$.

Hence there is a pushforward measure $X_*P$ on $(E^I,\mathcal{F})$ defined by $(X_*P)(A) = P(X \in A)$, and this pushforward measure is usually called the $law$ (or distribution) of $X$. My best guess is that $\mathcal{L}[X]$ refers to this pushforward measure.

It can be proved that if $Y=(Y_t)_{t \in I}$ is another stochastic process on $E$ such that the finite-dimensional distributions of $Y$ agree with the finite-dimensional distributions of $X$, then $\mathcal{L}[X]=\mathcal{L}[Y]$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_%28stochastic_processes%29

Comment: This is certainly one way to do it.  However, more commonly one deals with processes that have some regularity, and uses smaller path spaces.  For instance, if $X$ is a continuous process (i.e. the map $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is continuous for every, or almost every, $\omega$), then we may instead view $X$ as a mapping from $\Omega$ into the space $C(I,E)$ of continuous functions from $I$ to $E$, equipped with something like the Borel $\sigma$-algebra coming from the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

Comment: Then the distribution of $X$ is the pushforward measure on $C(I,E)$.  This has the advantage that it gives you a finer $\sigma$-algebra and hence more measurable sets.  For cadlag processes, you might replace $E^I$ with the Skorohod path space.

Comment: Have you a reference for the proof of $\mathcal{L}[X]=\mathcal{L}[Y]$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You want to show that $X_*P=Y_*P$, so just use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem (applied to the $\pi$-system consisting of all sets of the form $\bigcap_1^n \pi_i^{-1}(B_i)$).

Comment: @NateEldredge I know that this question is old, but if $E$ is separable the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated on the Skorohod path space should be $\sigma(\pi_t:t\in I)$. Am I missing something or did you had non-separable $E$ in mind?

Comment: To help with intuition, this formulation of the $\sigma$-algebra of $E^I$ is equivalent to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$ when $I \subset \mathbb Z$. 

For general $I \subset \mathbb R$, an explicit formula for $\mathcal L[X](A)$ when $A \subset E^I$ is of the form $A = \{f : f(t) \in A_t\}$ for fixed $A_t$ would be $$\mathcal L[X](A) = \mathbb P[X \in A] = \mathbb P\left[ \mathop\bigcap_{t \in I} \left\{ X_t \in A_t \right\}\right]$$

Comment: @DFord note that in order for such a set to be measurable wrt the product sigma algebra on $E^I$, all but countable many of the sets $A_t$ must be equal to $E$. This holds true for any indexing set $I$.

Comment: @Shalop yes this is true, and the scenario I pointed out with the product $\sigma$-algebra was when $I \subset \mathbb Z$. I don't seem to be able to edit my response sadly...